# working on shapefiles in ArcGIS for creating buffering on multiple shapefiles

Tags: gis, buffering

I am working on multiple shapefiles at once and I want to shift the shapefiles in a particular direction by 15m at the same time keeping the original shapefile on place. Kindly guide me for the same.

description of my task to be done

[image: 1]

I have tried through buffering, but its is not giving the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, it could be solved using a custom projection. I'm not sure if you use ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap. This description works for ArcMap:

- Use *toolboxes* → *data management* → *projections and transformations* → *project* and choose your dataset as input
- As target system, *copy and modify* the actually defined crs and add 15 meters to *false northig*
- Execute tool
- remove the new created layer from map window, as it prevents the following step
- Edit the **new** created shapefiles properties
- Switch to *xy ccordinate system* and define it back to the original system

If this works for you, you could try to automate it via the model builder.
(I use a german version of ArcMap, the propper english naming could differ a little bit)

Example for germany, using 1500 m shift

[image: Moved geometries]

Another option would be to use [FME Workbench](https://www.safe.com). It includes the [offsetter](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/offsetter.htm) and is afaik free to try for 30 days. Also it is very usefull for batch transformations.

Additional idea: solve it, using arcpy like this:

```py
from glob import glob
import os
# Adjust paths to your needs.
# Remember to end  with /
source_dir='C:/temp/'
target_path='C:/temp/projected/'
#Add original crs definition
source_crs="PROJCS['DHDN_3_Degree_Gauss_Zone_4',GEOGCS['GCS_Deutsches_Hauptdreiecksnetz',DATUM['D_Deutsches_Hauptdreiecksnetz',SPHEROID['Bessel_1841',6377397.155,299.1528128]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION['Gauss_Kruger'],PARAMETER['False_Easting',4500000.0],PARAMETER['False_Northing',0.0],PARAMETER['Central_Meridian',12.0],PARAMETER['Scale_Factor',1.0],PARAMETER['Latitude_Of_Origin',0.0],UNIT['Meter',1.0]]"
#Add offset to crs definition
target_crs="PROJCS['DHDN_3_Degree_Gauss_Zone_4',GEOGCS['GCS_Deutsches_Hauptdreiecksnetz',DATUM['D_Deutsches_Hauptdreiecksnetz',SPHEROID['Bessel_1841',6377397.155,299.1528128]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION['Gauss_Kruger'],PARAMETER['False_Easting',4500000.0],PARAMETER['False_Northing',15000.0],PARAMETER['Central_Meridian',12.0],PARAMETER['Scale_Factor',1.0],PARAMETER['Latitude_Of_Origin',0.0],UNIT['Meter',1.0]]"


#no user serviceable parts inside ;-)
files = glob(source_dir + '*.shp')
arcpy.env.addOutputsToMap = 0
for in_file in files:
    print("processing " + in_file)
    out_file = target_path+os.path.basename(in_file) 
    arcpy.Project_management(
        in_dataset=in_file, 
        out_dataset=out_file, 
        out_coor_system=target_crs,
        transform_method="",
        in_coor_system=source_crs,
        preserve_shape="NO_PRESERVE_SHAPE",
        max_deviation="",
        vertical="NO_VERTICAL")
    arcpy.DefineProjection_management(in_dataset=out_file, coor_system=source_crs)
```